# Scrum : Different Product owner and Project Manager

Tags: scrum

I have created a short document of two authors : Ken Swchaber and Jeff Sutherland. At definition in this document about Product Owner:

> The Product Owner is the sole person responsible for managing the
>   Product Backlog

I see that `Product owner` is very like to `Project  Manager` in normal software development process.

So, what does a real difference, or just the same.

Comment: close with no comment again ! I don't know how can he/she do that :))

Comment: This question is not fit for stackoverflow. I think it's better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Ikke many many questions here about scrum, agile, and none of them is close. And I dont know the reason why my post has down vote :|

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Product Owner and a Project Manager are quite different.

On a traditional project, a Project Manager, as the title implies, manages a project.

However, on a Scrum project, the Development Team manages their own work.

The Product Owner, while responsible for maximizing the value of the product and the work of the Development Team, is the sole person responsible for managing the Product Backlog.

Product Backlog Management includes:

- Clearly expressing Product Backlog items;
- Ordering the items in the Product Backlog to best achieve goals and missions;
- Ensuring the value of the work the Development Team performs;
- Ensuring that the Product Backlog is visible, transparent, and clear to all, and shows
  what the Scrum Team will work on next;
- Ensuring the Development Team understands items in the Product Backlog to the level needed.

Hope that helps. More details available in this article on the [need for Product Owners](https://turboscrum.com/scrum-product-owner-role-necessary/)

Answer (score 2):

The difference is subtle, because we tend to infer a lot from the phrase "manage the backlog".

While a PM is often responsible for coordinating HOW the initiative should be accomplished, the Product Owner is responsible for understanding WHAT the product show do and works with the team to make sure this is reflected in the list of items (often described in business terms as features) called the Product Backlog.

In Scrum, the Development Team (composed of all skills needed to produce a complete increment in an iteration) is responsible for determining HOW to accomplish the items selected for completion in an iteration.

Answer (score 2):

I think you ask this because you don't understand so much about agile.

Project Manager : he decides EVERYTHING, and tester, developers... often don't talk together, they must talk with project manager, and project manager will give this idea to other. for example : developer says : "I have add this feature A". and project manager will says to tester : "Hey, you should add a unit test for feature A", for example.

Product Owner : yeah, Project Manager can be a Product Owner, or, your customer can be product owner, too. It means : Product Owner : the person who can control the flow how the software is !
More over, product owner : he just looks how you work and give some talk to control the FLOW, not control your activity.